# Matplotlib: разделение/масштабирование графиков

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

я имею несколько гистограмм. Проблема в том, что, если выводить их в Figure на одной системе координат, то несмотря на то, что мастштаб очень хорошо визуализирует разницу между ними, при этом все очень скомкано, ничего не видно. Если же для каждого графика создавать свои оси, то тогда визуально выходит очень некрасиво
Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то исправить эту ситуацию, то есть сделать так, чтобы на разделенных осях графики выглядели так же, как на первой картинке?
[image: *]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sc
from scipy.stats import pareto
import scipy.stats as sts

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
b = 15
x = np.linspace(pareto.ppf(0.01, b),
                pareto.ppf(0.99, b),
                100
                )
y = pareto.pdf(x, b)
plt.plot(x,
         y,
         color='maroon',
         lw=6, alpha=0.8,
         label='Pareto Function PDF'
         )
plt.hist(pareto.rvs(b, size=1000),
         density=True,
         color='aqua',
         histtype='stepfilled',
         alpha=0.8,
         label='Generated Pareto function sample'
         )
samples_size_list = [1, 3, 8, 30, 100]
rand_count = 1000
sample_mean_matrix = np.zeros((len(samples_size_list), rand_count))

for i in range(len(samples_size_list)):
    for j in range(rand_count):
        sample_mean_matrix[i, j] = sum(pareto.rvs(b, size=samples_size_list[i])) \
                                   / float(samples_size_list[i])


for current_list, i in zip(sample_mean_matrix, range(len(samples_size_list))):
    plt.figure()
    mean, var = pareto.stats(b, moments='mv')
    fit = sts.norm.pdf(x, mean, sc.sqrt(var/samples_size_list[i]))
    plt.plot(x, fit, '-')
    plt.hist(current_list,
             histtype='stepfilled',
             density=True,
             alpha=0.6,
             )

plt.show()
```

[image: **]

Comment: А где ваш код и пример исходных данных? или ответ "можно" вас устроит?

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Надо указать для каждого из графиков

```
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
```

Значения параметров, естественно, одинаковы для всех графиков.
Поскольку вы свой код не представили, придется вам вставлять указанную строчку самому.

А вообще-то гистограммы для нескольких графиков использовать не рекомендуют. Обычно достаточно построить boxplots, что-бы извлечь базовую информацию для сравнения. Вот там их можно на один график хоть десяток. А уж более точно сравнивать гистограммы, например, попарно. Впрочем - так обычно и происходит при сравнении функций плотностей распределения  при проверке гипотез.

Comment: Ой, а я на самом деле и делаю то, что вы сказали. Извините, не подскажете, как можно реализовать данную задачу с помощью boxplots? Код прикрепил

Comment: Если вы "на самом деле и делаю то" о чем я написал, тогда непонятно, почему  в приложенном вами коде это не так и почему на приложенной вами картинке (второй)  для каждой гистограммы свой масштаб по оси Y.  А какую задачу  вы  вообще реализуете - сие нам не ведомо.